# Why is my validation rule not working as needed?

Tags: validation-rule

I want the validation to require both the 'AuditReviewed' and 'AuditEntered' to be TRUE before moving the Opp to a new stage. For now, it allows me to move the stage with just one of those two. I would appreciate the help with this.

```
AND(
ApplySavings__c=TRUE,
RecordType.Name="TEST Opportunity Record Type",
NOT(CONTAINS($Profile.Name, "System")),
ISCHANGED(StageName),
AuditReviewed__c=FALSE,
AuditEntered__c=FALSE,
OR(
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Presentation"),
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Handling Objections"),
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Acceptance"),
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Admin Review"),
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won")))
```

Comment: you should look at the PRIORVALUE function for use in Stagename OR block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem; you've used AND when you should have used OR. While we sometimes use AND to mean "either" in colloquial English, in computer logic, we need to examine a truth table.

| AND Truth Table | true | false |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | **true** | false |
| false | false | false |

| OR Truth Table | true | false |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | true |
| false | true | **false** |

We want the validation rule to return false only when both checkboxes are checked, so we need to use OR here, or use [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to convert this so both boxes must be checked:

```
OR(
  AuditReviewed__c=FALSE,
  AuditEntered__c=FALSE
),
```

Or with de Morgan's Laws:

```
NOT(AND(AuditReviewed__c, AuditEntered__c))
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks a lot for your explanation as it relates to the usage of AND and OR in validation rules. This was my first validation rule experience in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules are better thought of as *in*validation rules. Instead of trying to describe when your data is valid, you're describing when your data is invalid.

Let's work on a simplified version of your rule

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(StageName),
    AuditReviewed__c = FALSE,
    AuditEntered__c = FALSE
)
```

When this expression evaluates to `TRUE`, your validation rule complains and prevents the operation. Using `AND` here for everything makes it so that if any one of those conditions is false, the entire thing evaluates to false, and the validation rule lets the operation proceed.

Starting by writing things out in plain language can help here.

Your initial requirement was "if field1 and field 2 are true, allow the operation".

Keeping in mind that you're writing an (in)validation rule, you want to describe when the operation should be prevented. "if field1 or field2 are false, disallow the operation".

From there, it should be simple to see that you need to check your field values in an `OR` instead of an `AND`

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(StageName),
    OR(
        AuditReviewed__c = false,
        AuditEntered__c = false
    )
)
```